# Case, Is Null and a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that i'd like to have display "0" if the "Tip" is "NULL" otherwise just display the tip. This is my query:

```
SELECT t1.sName         ,
       t1.sLocationDesc ,
       t1.sOtherNumber  ,
       t1.RegHours      ,
       t1.OTHours       ,
       CASE
         WHEN t2.EmployeeHours / t3.DepartmentHrs * @Tip IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE t2.EmployeeHours / t3.DepartmentHrs * @Tip
       END AS Tip
```

I receive an error:

> Incoming Tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocal stream is incorrect.  Parameter 3 ("@Tip") User-defined type
>   has an invalid user type specified..

Any help here?

Comment: I think the issue lies with your definition of @Tip. Can we see the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use case

just try this

```
SELECT t1.sName, 
       t1.sLocationDesc, 
       t1.sOtherNumber, 
       t1.RegHours, 
       t1.OTHours, 
       ISNULL(t2.EmployeeHours / t3.DepartmentHrs * @Tip,0) AS 'Tip'
```

BTW I feel the error is not due to your case statement

Comment: This is perfect.  I didn't know you could use this.  Is there documentation somewhere on this you could provide so I can understand where I can use this?  Thank you!!

Comment: check this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that if `@Tip` is 0, you'll get a divide by zero error.

Comment: @icemanind yes but this solution is considering the variable Tip was taken care of , else you can also do a ISNULL check on Tip too

Comment: @KarthikGanesan - that won't work either. `ISNULL` only checks for NULL values. It doesn't check for values that are 0.

Comment: ohh yes... sorry my bad

Comment: You probably want to change the expression to check for zero so as to prevent zero divide errors: `coalesce(case t3.DepartmentHours*@Tip when 0 then 0 else t2.EmployeeHours/t3.DepartmentHrs * @Tip end , 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.sName, t1.sLocationDesc, t1.sOtherNumber, t1.RegHours, t1.OTHours,
       CASE WHEN (@Tip IS NULL OR @Tip=0) THEN 0 ELSE 
       t2.EmployeeHours/t3.DepartmentHrs * @Tip END AS Tip
```

Comment: This returns the same error.  The problem is, I care more about the result of "TIP" being "NULL" not @Tip being Null.  In my test "@TIP" is assigned "100" and it errors on my query, and yours.

Comment: @Shmewnix - Can you post the definition for @Tip?

Comment: That's the only reference.  It's a user-defined type in the select clause.

Comment: Try changing all occurrences of `@Tip` with 0 and see if it works. If it does, try changing all occurrences of @Tip with 1 and see if that works too. If both of these works, then there is something wrong with your `@Tip` definition